# Nonnegative analytic function as a square

Tags: real-analysis, complex-analysis, analyticity

It is know that if $f:\mathbb{C}\to \mathbb{C}^*$ is a continuous function, then for every $n>0$ there exists a continuous function $g:\mathbb{C}\to \mathbb{C}^*$ such that $f=g^n$.

Is it true that if $f$ is analytic then $g$ can be chosen analytic?

What happens in the real case? For example, if $n=2$, is it true that if $f:\mathbb{R}\to \mathbb{R}^+_0$ is analytic then there exists $g:\mathbb{R}\to \mathbb{R}$ analytic such that $f=g^2$ ?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, this is true. If $f$ is entire and zero-free, there is a well defined holomorphic logarithm of $f$, (i.e. $f = e^g$ for some entire function $g$).

You can take $e^{g/n}$ as an $n$:th root of $f$.

Answer (score 0):

I would say yes: extend the Real-Analytic function $f$ into a Complex -Analytic one $f_2$ , which will not be zero, since the Real part is never 0. Then $f_2$ will have a square root, whose Real part will coincide with $f$.

Comment: What do you mean with "real part of a complex function"? If it is $(h+\overline{h})/2$, I didn't understand what you meant. Otherwise, if it is the restriction of a complex function to $\mathbb{R}$, you have said that if $g:\mathbb{C}\to \mathbb{C}^*$ is such that $g^2=f_2$ on $\mathbb{C}$ then $(g\mid_{\mathbb{R}})^2=f$ on $\mathbb{R}$. But why is $g\mid_{\mathbb{R}}$ real-valued?

Comment: I mean use Cauchy -Riemann to extend $f$ into a Complex -Analytic function $f+ig$ by requiring $g$ to satisfy Cauchy-Riemann equations. And $g |_{\mathbb R}$ would be given by $g_1(x,y)+ig_2(x,y)$ so that the Real part $ g_1$ squares into Reals; by closedness of operations on Real numbers.

Comment: Let me double -check and will get back to you.

Comment: user72870: I think this works: take $f$ and turn it into $if$. Then extend $if$ into the Complex-Analytic function $h=g+if$. Since f is never $0$, then $h$ itself is never $0$ so that it has a square root $S_h:=S_1+iS_2$ and  $S_h^2= S_1^2-S_2^2 +i(S_1S_2)=g+if$. Then $S_1S_2=f$, our original function $f$. But then $f=S_1S_2$ , the product of Real -Analytic functions is  Real -Analytic ad we are done.